# Using URL hash check to load jQuery tabs different ways

Tags: jquery, hash, jquery-tabs

My site is running jQuery 1.6.2.  This I cannot change.

I am trying to check if a #hash is present in the url and load a jQuery tabs to a specific tab, like so...

```
    if(window.location.hash == '#rates') {
        $("#tabs").tabs({
            show: { effect: "slideDown", duration: 300 },
            hide: { effect: "fade", duration: 300 },
            active: 4
        )};
    } else {
        $("#tabs").tabs({
            show: { effect: "slideDown", duration: 300 },
            hide: { effect: "fade", duration: 300 }
        });
    }
```

It's not working and just breaks jQuery tabs.  If i remove all the if / else and just have the following...

```
        $("#tabs").tabs({
            show: { effect: "slideDown", duration: 300 },
            hide: { effect: "fade", duration: 300 },
            active: 4
        });
```

it works as expected.  Does anyone know what could be causing this issue?  I'm wondering if it's just jQuery version that doesn't like how I wrote it... I know similar stuff works fine on other site's I've worked on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've messed up the closing parenthesis in the `if` part

```
if(window.location.hash == '#rates') {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        show: { effect: "slideDown", duration: 300 },
        hide: { effect: "fade", duration: 300 },
        active: 4
    });    // was )};
} else {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        show: { effect: "slideDown", duration: 300 },
        hide: { effect: "fade", duration: 300 }
    });
}
```

Comment: WOW.  I can't believe I just typo'd and that was the issue.  Thanks for spotting that.  It's all working now.